# Is is possible to use npm local-devices in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to scan **local network devices** and get their info like ip, mac-address etc. and [local-devices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-devices) package claims that it can provide me such info.
I have installed and used that package, but giving errors like `os, net, mz/process` modules not found.
I have also installed `os, net and mz` but still giving errors.
So how it can be used smoothly?

Comment: The package you found is intended to work on a server (nodejs) and not in a browser ?

Comment: So at any cost it won't work. ;(

Comment: Javascript is a high-level language. Chrome's V8 engine is written in c++,
For security reason, JavaScript does not allow the reading or writing of files.

Since Reading or writing files is not possible in javascript, you won't be able to do the same in angular as well. (Angular is a javascript framework).

Although You can achieve those task via  c++ and since v8 is written in c++ you can add functionality to v8 to read/write the files, Nodejs does the same. unfortunately, the changes you made in v8 won't be added to peoples browsers, so long story short you wont be able to do that.

Comment: What language V8 is written in doesn't have anything to do with what you can do with it...